# How to import GUID columns from SQL database via External Content Type in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am trying to read some columns from my CRM database in SharePoint 2010 list using external content type via SharePoint Designer 2010. But the GUID fields are refusing to be imported. By this, what I mean is, when I create an External List based on the External Content Type created in SPD, the list doesnt show the fields that are of GUID type. There is no error messages, warnings, or log file entries that explains this. Any ideas as to why this may be happening?

I am not trying to edit or write back to the database, simply read. I can read/see other fields fine in the destination list.

Comment: "Refusing to be imported" means what? It threw an exception (what exception)?  You can't compile/save/X? It compiled fine, doesn't throw an exception but it isn't doing a thing... What do the various logs have to say about the import you've attempted. Just a few of the many ways you can [ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the exact same issue.  For me I was hoping to Edit the GUID or add it, but since the External List does not show the GUID at all I can't do any of that.  You stated you just need to read it though.  You can get the GUID type columns to show up by creating a new PAGE and adding a Web part of type 'business data list' which connects to your External Content Type.  Look at the link below...specifically the part half way down entitled "Deploy the solution and create new page to see the associated data lists".  It is very useful to link up data between tables too using Business Data Related Lists.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vssharepointtoolsblog/archive/2010/08/02/walkthrough-of-creating-association-between-sharepoint-bdc-entities-using-visual-studio-2010.aspx